# What are the minimal requirement for building non-enemy spawnable regions?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I just started playing Terraria for iOS (yeah, I know I'm late to the party) and I'm wanting to build a HUGE safe structure that's both above and below ground.

I'd like to clear out the area and make a barebones structure, first, and later I'll fill any additional materials, furniture, etc.

What are the minimal requirements for making a region, for lack of a better term, where enemies will not spawn?

Comment: If your question is about terraria on mobile don't use the terraria tag too.

Comment: @N_palum, I apologize.  While looking at the tags, I thought I saw tags for the mobile & PC versions, as well as the [terraria] tag, which I assumed was a generic question, potentially related to both.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the area in which you want no enemies to spawn is closed up, with walls and light sources around. That should make sure no enemies spawn. Any building that fits the housing requirements works as well.

*Most important is the walls

Comment: When you say walls, do you mean the background "Wall" material, or strictly a "wall" like stone, which you can't pass through.  I ask, because I'd like to save time by clearing out the background walls, unless they are required.

Comment: @RLH  I mean background walls, it's the only way for those pesky enemies to not spawn in your house/building :)

Comment: On a related note - the background walls *must be player-placed* in order to prevent mobs from spawning. If you just dig out a huge cave and leave all the dirt walls there, you'll still get mobs. If you remove all of the dirt walls and replace them with dirt walls that you've crafted yourself, then mobs won't spawn.

Comment: @MageXy unless you find an underground house, those won't spawn mobs, even though the wooden walls aren't player placed.